# Doctrine many to one relationship versioning

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I have an application that I'm developing in symfony 2 with doctrine. The problem I'm facing is the slowly changing dimension.

For example I have three Entities: Dossier, Payout and PayoutCategory. Dossier has a many to one relationship with Payout and Payout a many to one relationship with PayoutCategory.

The important part is the relation between a Payout and a PayoutCategory. The PayoutCategory contains 2 important fields: *ceiling* and *procentual*. The ceiling describes the maximum allowed payout of a dossier. Since a dossier can have serveral payouts of the **same** PayoutCategory all these payouts are counted together and multiplied by the procentual field. The total of the calculation is either smaller or equal to the ceiling if not ceiling value is returned. Now if either the ceiling or procentual (or the name) field gets updated the previous made dossiers are also changed. So my question is there a bundle out there that handles this problem? Because I have several relationships similar to this one.

I have tried the builtin doctrine [loggable behaviour](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md) and the [EntityAuditBundle](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit) but they don't solve this. Although they add a version field to PayoutCategory the version field is just to track changes of the entity itself. In fact I need the version field as part of the relationship (foreign key in Payout) between Payout and PayoutCategory.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I ended up creating a copy of the entity and deleting the old one. This seems like an extremely dirty and inefficient way to go about things, but it works, if it leaves a lot of redundant data in the DB.

Comment: @bluppfisk srry for late answer my new job doesn't require SO that much. Anyway I also came up with a solution similar to yours. I created an entity with a composite primary key containing name and version. Then I checked if either the field ceiling or procentual changed and when it does I duplicate the entity and increment the version. This way I can track the changes and keep the old ones but there are also some disadvantages primarily the composite key in doctrine. On the other hand I could've also just duplicated the PayoutCategory as JSON in the Payout entity.